# disable qTranslate when logged in (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, qtranslate

I want to disable a plugin "qTranslate" when logged in.

I know that I can do that with this function :" if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ... } ", but I have no idea where should I use this..any help?

Thanks

Comment: Disable which functionality of qTranslate? If you explain I could help.

Comment: You can utilize this technic discussed here:http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41925/disable-qtranslate-by-post-type-in-admin-disable-per-page-post-id-on-front-e

If you need help, reply, I'll answer.

Answer (score -1):

Tell me if you got luck with the following:

```
function qtrans_disable()
  {
   global $typenow, $pagenow;

 if (in_array($typenow, array('post')) &&
    in_array($pagenow, array('post-new.php', 'post.php'))) 
  {
    remove_action('admin_head',   'qtrans_adminHeader'     );
    remove_filter('admin_footer', 'qtrans_modifyExcerpt'   );
    remove_filter('the_editor',   'qtrans_modifyRichEditor');
  }
 }
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) 
 {
 add_action('current_screen', 'qtrans_disable');
 }
```